# Setting Breaktpoints in Spyder doesn't work

Tags: python, debugging, breakpoints, spyder

I'm very new working with Python and Spyder. I use Python 3.5 and Spyder 2.3.8. I wanted to debug my code and set a breakpoint. Then this error appeared in the Internal console:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\plugins\externalconsole.py", line 713, in set_spyder_breakpoints
         shellwidget.shell.set_spyder_breakpoints()    
    AttributeError: 'TerminalWidget' object has no attribute 'set_spyder_breakpoints'
```

When I run the code the breakpoints are ignored.
Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed Spyder through conda?

Comment: @Leb yes I installed Anaconda and Spyder was included there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I want breakpoints to be taken into account, I often forget to launch my code:

- via the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> icon (the blue arrow + double-bar),
- instead of  the usual <kbd>F5</kbd> (the green arrow).